# Can't schedule refresh in PowerBI Service

Tags: service, powerbi, refresh, schedule

I have a PowerBI report with 2 tables sourced from separate web API calls to a similar service, let's call it MyService.  The service returns json.  The report refreshes perfectly within PBI Desktop.  The report publishes to PowerBI.com where it runs without a hitch.  On-demand refresh of the report's dataset in the PBI Service works perfectly too.

[image: Refresh History]

I can't schedule a refresh for this report because the option is greyed out.  There is an error reported in the Data source credentials section where one of the two Web sources reports it cannot connect to MyService.  The error is... "Your data source can't be refreshed because the credentials are invalid. Please update your credentials and try again."

[image: Data source credentials]

Attempting to edit the credentials for the failing connection results in a 500 Internal Server Error.

This error is unexpected because I understood the on-demand refreshes & scheduled refreshes would use the same data source(s).  There is no where to specify different data sources/credentials for on-demand vs. scheduled so I just assume they share the same sets of credentials.

Is something weird going on or does my understanding of the innards of the PBI Service need realignment?

Comment: Try referring this article... https://zappysys.com/blog/howto-import-json-rest-api-power-bi/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_OzrBRDmARIsAAIdQ_IOGO5_EvtHZCr1WJUtkiZREd6521xGQKotPf88EQ-QAi4V2cNDmmcaAnqdEALw_wcB It looks more useful to your requirement...

Comment: Introducing a 3rd party ODBC connection seems excessive.  Surely the built-in Web connector is sufficient.  The built-in connector works for other reports in the same PBI instance, connecting to the same remote API.

Comment: Are you using Basic Authentication?  That's the only thing that works for me with my JSON connections.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved via workaround...

PROBLEM

Dataset credentials cannot be updated without causing 500 error.  Invalid credentials disables scheduled refresh options.  When publishing a .pbix file via PBI Desktop to PBI Service it may fail to update the dataset connection in the service, leaving it in an invalid state.  Refreshes cannot be scheduled while there are any invalid dataset connections.

WORKAROUND

Open the same .pbix file via PBI Service (i.e. PowerBI.com --> GetData), and the dataset connection will be updated.  Credentials can now be set without error, thus allowing scheduled refreshes to be set.

Comment: can you ellaborate on this part "Open the same .pbix file via PBI Service (i.e. PowerBI.com --> GetData)"? Where is that on app.powerbi.com?

Comment: I tried "Open the same .pbix file via PBI Service (i.e. PowerBI.com --> GetData)" and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If schedule refresh to be worked without gateway, then your data source should be online/cloud or on sharepoint. else you require gateway. ensure all your data sources for .pbix file has cloud only/share point only as source, if its from offline file & online then simply scheduling does not work, you need to setup gateway.